# fluentd unable/Notable to connect to elasticsearch when es is installed on different port

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

in my docker environment there is  elastic search(ES-1) exposed to port 9200 , this is main ES to maintain DB data , so for the sake of logging we are using fluentd-elasticsearch-kibna stack with new elastic search running on port 9700(ES-2) .

I am unable to connect fluentd to this new elastic search(ES-2) to port 9700. Let me know how to connect fluentd to es other than port "9200"

below are the docker config details using for F-E-K

```
 fluentd.config :
    <source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearchkibana
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>


docker-compose.yml :

   version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        tag: httpd.access

  elasticsearchkibana:
    image: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    expose:
      - 9800
    ports:
      - "9700:9300"
      - "9800:9200"

  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    links:
      - "elasticsearchkibana"
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"

  kibana:
    image: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearchkibana:9200
#      - "ES_HOST=192.168.241.82"
#      - "ES_PORT=9700"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
```

Below is the ERROR MESSAGE i am getting when i use above configuration

```
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:36 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:16:37 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:37 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:37 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:39 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:16:37 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:37 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:16:39 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:39 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:39 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:43 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:16:39 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:39 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:16:43 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:43 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:43 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:50 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:16:43 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:43 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:16:50 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:16:50 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:50 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:17:04 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:16:50 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:16:50 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:17:04 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:17:04 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:17:04 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:17:39 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:17:04 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:17:04 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:17:39 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:17:39 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:17:39 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:18:46 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:17:39 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:18:46 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:18:46 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:17:39 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:18:46 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:20:49 +0000 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!" plugin_id="object:2af57e68ced4"
fluentd_1              |   2017-09-25 15:18:46 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
fluentd_1              | 2017-09-25 15:18:46 +0000 fluent.warn: {"next_retry":"2017-09-25 15:20:49 +0000","error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2af57e68ced4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-25 15:20:49 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"localhost\\\", :port=>9700, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"})!\" plugin_id=\"object:2af57e68ced4\""}
root@docker-test:/home/tlirlogin/docker-compose-efk-master2# cd fluentd/conf/
```

Thanks

Comment: Your fluentd is running inside the container network and not the host. So the port still needs to be 9200 even though you map to 9700 on host. Because the connection depends on the container port in this case

Comment: @tarun Laiwani 
still getting error when changed
fluentd_1  fluent.warn: error_class":"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure","error":"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearchkibana\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\"})!","plugin_id":"object:2ac5be462aa4","message":"temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2017-09-26 05:14:24 +0000 error_class=\"Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure\" error=\"Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster

Comment: Can you share the fluentd dockerfile? So I can give your compose file a shot

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hi i edited the question with new configuration please find..Thanks

Comment: I am not looking for config, I need the Dockerfile you used for the fluentd build

Comment: Please find the dockerfile:
FROM fluent/fluentd:v0.12
RUN ["gem", "install", "fluent-plugin-elasticsearch", "--no-rdoc", "--no-ri", "--version", "1.9.5"]

Comment: There is no issue, you will see that message for few seconds because it sometime for ES to get up, after that you won't see the connection issue. I tested locally and it works after few seconds

Comment: Thanks!!! that helped a lot , now i am able to logs from all containers and store in Es , just need to check with kibana interface..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your fluentd config as below

```
fluentd.config :
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearchkibana
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

So basically add `host elasticsearchkibana` and change to `port 9200`. This is because we should be concerned about the container port and not the host port